# Mysql Insert Into Error

Tags: php

I've created a registration form and I'm adding the data with php but for some reason it will not let me add the data into the database.  Can you see anything wrong with this code?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die("No Connection");;
mysql_select_db("music") or die("No Database");;

$username= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["username"]);
$password= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["password"]);
$email= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["email"]);
$hash = md5( rand(0,1000) );

mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (id, username, password, email, hash, active) VALUES('', '$username', '$password', '$email', '$hash', '')") or die("Can't Add");
if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
echo "1";
}else{
echo "2";
}
?>
```

I Keep getting a Can't Add error indicating that there is a simple problem with the mysql_query row

Thank you

Comment: What is indicated problem? the error message u gets?

Comment: I think its in the id. insert query will not execute if primary keys are the same.

Comment: what are you using? wamp ?

Comment: Just remove the id and the the '' corresponding to the id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Can't add` is not an error, just a catch all statement you added at the end.

To see your *actual* problem, change your code at the end of the `mysql_query` line to include the actual error retrieved from `mysql_error()`.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username, password, email, hash, active) VALUES('$username', '$password', '$email', '$hash', '')")
    or die("Can't Add - " . mysql_error());
```

That will give you more details regarding the error, if you post that, I can update my answer with the reason why.

*Note that I've also removed the insertion of `id`, it's not needed if your column is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which it should be.*

Comment: Thank You - I ran the error code and found the problem - It was to do with the id column - It's not an auto_incriment but the id is made up of a unique code based on time + random numbers - Sorted now and the registration form works just fine - Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

if id is your primary key then replane '' with null

Answer (score 0):

Make `id` as `auto-incremented` `primary key` and remove it from insert query.

Answer (score 0):

there may be unique constraints for any of the column

Answer (score 0):

Either have

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (id, username, password, email, hash, active) 
             VALUES(null, '$username', '$password', '$email', '$hash', '')") or die("Can't Add");
                    ^^^^
```

### OR

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username, password, email, hash, active) 
             VALUES( '$username', '$password', '$email', '$hash', '')") or die("Can't Add");
```